# Editing index.html hosted on github pages

Tags: html, github, github-pages

I have to make a very simple modification to a website which is being hosted on github pages (I just want to change the title in the index.html).

For simplicity I'd like to just modify and commit the change directly in the github code editor.

If I go to the github repo > Settings > Pages, I see that the under source it says "Your GitHub Pages site is currently being built from the gh-pages branch."

I have to switch from my master branch to the gh-pages branch to make the modifications and commit.

However I am not seeing any changes to the page, even after clearing the cache.

Am I misunderstanding how the github pages hosting works?

Answer (score 0):

When you go to settings > Pages, you will see a dropdown menu for choosing which branch you want to post you website on. Just choose **master** .
After that you can easily edit whatever you want from github editor and then you have to commit the changes.
And after that you have to be a little patient till github servers save the changes and publish them for you.